# Can I pre-process LESS files with grunt using generic filepaths?

Tags: javascript, css, less, gruntjs

I have several LESS files to compile, but I will not need to concatenate them. I need a CSS file to be created for each LESS file, with the same filename (except for the ending).

Here's the LESS task in my gruntfile, as it is:

```
less: {
      dev: {
        files: {
          "css/esccore.css": "less/esccore.less",
          "css/escdocument.css": "less/escdocument.less",
          "css/escportal-top.css": "less/escportal-top.less",
          "css/report-fancy-top.css": "less/report-fancy-top.less",
          "css/report-plain-top.css": "less/report-plain-top.less",
          "css/report-blue-top.css": "less/report-blue-top.less"
        }
      },
      build: {
        //build configurations
      }
    },
```

So, as of now, every time I create a new LESS file, I need to add it to my gruntfile. Is there a way to automate this? So that Grunt scans all of the LESS files in my less folder, and creates a new file for each in a coinciding CSS folder (using the same basic filename)?

Comment: You can use a anonymous function that walks through your directory, generates the key/value pairs and returns that object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the files array format like:

```
less: {
    dev: {
        files: [
            {
                expand: true,
                src: ['less/*.less'],
                dest: 'css/',
                ext: '.css',

            }
        ]
    },
    build: {
        //buildconfigurations
    }
}
```

Doc: http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically